# Using an Access Query in a pivot table in Excel

Tags: excel, ms-access

I have a ton of records across 5 different tables in Access that I'm consolidating in one query.

I want to now be able to connect that query to excel and pivot the data that is in the query. Is that possible? If so, is there a way to do it without added VBA? I was thinking of slowly exporting the consolidated data into a new table in access but with over 7 million records, it'll take some time. Anyway to save myself that headache? When I connect the DB to excel, the only tables that are coming up are the 5 tables and not the query.

Comment: You can connect Access to Excel just using Assistant. In the Options Ribbon, tab Data, Get External Data, and there is an option for Access. I get my data from queries using it sometimes. Is your query a Select one?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns it is but when I use the assistant the only option thats coming up to select is the 5 tables and not the query. Also, when I connect it without selecting a table, a general query loads and tells me the tables that are in the DB but not the query that consolidates everything.

Comment: If the query does not appear in the list, maybe is not a "normal select" query. It happens sometimes. Have you tried a normal common select query that selects the fields of your consolidation query, and then see if that new query appears in the assistant. Sometimes this worked for me. I make a query that consolidates all, and then I make a new query that calls all the fields in the consolidation query. I know this can sound weird, but maybe it will work for you without using VBA

Comment: Anyways, Excel cannot have 7 millions records in the same sheet. Does your consolidation query returns 7 millions records? :O